# How to hide play audio interface in Safari from javascript on Apple Macbook Pro with keyboard Touch Bar

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio

We have an app that frequently plays short audio snippets.  With the newest Apple Macbook Pro with the Touch Bar, every time one of those short audio snippets play the touch bar switches to an audio interface - and switches back and forth from the web interface pretty rapidly.  This is likely not desirable for application users.

Is there a way at the javascript level to disable this behavior in Safari browser for an instance of `Audio()`?

Comment: You can't control that. That's the OS seeing that audio is being played and is raising an event for the hardware. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I figured.  Thanks for confirming.  Noting, the user can always disable that in Mac System Preferences, if annoyed.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this?